# How to delete unnecessary records from postgresql database table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that includes versions of my table.

```
version_id     transaction    entity_id    date
--------------------------------------------------------------
1              insert         1            11.11.2019 13:15:04
2              update         1            11.11.2019 13:16:04
3              insert         8            11.11.2019 13:17:04
4              update         1            11.11.2019 13:18:04
5              update         8            11.11.2019 13:19:04
6              update         1            11.11.2019 13:20:04
7              update         1            11.11.2019 13:21:04
8              delete         1            11.11.2019 13:22:04
```

For example entity id 1, I need 1,7,8 version numbers. 2,4,6 version numbers are not needed, so I can delete them. Actually I need last insert, update, delete transaction version numbers for an entity. The others will delete.

Can I remove all unnecessary update ids in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "last" is defined by the value of `date`, you can use this query to delete earlier versions:

```
DELETE FROM versions v1
WHERE date < (SELECT MAX(date)
              FROM versions v2
              WHERE v2.entity_id = v1.entity_id
                AND v2.transaction = v1.transaction)
```

Output (from `SELECT *` after `DELETE`) for your sample data:

```
version_id  transaction     entity_id   date
1           insert          1           2019-11-11T13:15:04.000Z
3           insert          8           2019-11-11T13:17:04.000Z
5           update          8           2019-11-11T13:19:04.000Z
7           update          1           2019-11-11T13:21:04.000Z
8           delete          1           2019-11-11T13:22:04.000Z
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rqWmLmWi8wHFkEX1oPkCK4/0)

Answer (score 1):

> I need last insert, update, delete transaction version numbers for an entity.

You can delete the rows using:

```
delete from version v
    where v.version_id < (select max(v2.version_id)
                          from versions v2
                          where v2.entity_id = v.entity_id and
                                v2.transaction = v.transaction
                         );
```